# Solutions for small perturbations

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I have the following exercise:

Let $f,g\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ bounded functions and $f(0)=0$. Show that for suitably small $\varepsilon>0$ the following problem has a solution:
$$
\begin{cases}
u''(t)=f(\varepsilon u(t))+\varepsilon g(t) \\
u(0)=0=u(1)
\end{cases}
$$

[Edit: the exercise hint is to use the implicit function theorem]

My attempted solution:

Let's consider the solution map
$$ 
T\colon (\varepsilon,u)\in B_r(0)\times C_0^2([0,1]) \mapsto u''(t)-f(\varepsilon u(t))-\varepsilon g(t)\in C([0,1])
$$

By hypotesis $T(0,0)=0$. We can use the implicit function theorem to prove the statement.

Let's consider its differential in the second variable:
$$D_u T(0,0)[h]=h''$$
which is continuous, injective (since all functions with null second derivative and null in $0$ and $1$ must be zero) and is surjective since for each $k(t)\in C([0,1])$, setting
$$ K(t)=\int_0^t\int_0^\tau k(s)\ ds \ d\tau$$
is such that $K''(t)=k(t)$. Therefore it's an isomorphism and by the implicit function theorem there exist $\delta$ and $\eta$ and a function $G\colon B_\delta(0)\rightarrow B_\eta(0)$ such that for each $\varepsilon \in B_\delta(0)$ we have $T(\varepsilon,G(\varepsilon))=0$.

Is this proof right? Have I not considered the role of $f$ and $g$ making some big mistake?

Comment: [Edit: the exercise hint is to use the implicit function theorem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You learn from $f(εu)\sim f'(0)εu$ and the ODE that $u=O(ε)$. Insert $u=εv$ so that 
$$
v''=\frac{f(ε^2v)}ε+g(t)=g(t)+O(ε)
$$
The reduced equation $v''=g$ has the solution
\begin{align}
v(t)&=v'(0)t+\int_0^t(t-s)g(s)ds  \\
0=v(1)&=v'(0)+\int_0^1(1-s)g(s)ds  \\
v(t)&=-\int_0^ts(1-t)g(s)ds-\int_t^1t(1-s)g(s)ds  \\
 &=\int_0^1G(t,s)g(s)ds,
\end{align}
that is, using the Green kernel for $L[u]=u''$.

Now use that to formulate a fixed-point operator $C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ 
$$
T[u](t)=\int_0^1G(t,s)[f(εu)+εg(s)]ds
$$
which is contractive for $ε$ small enough, certainly for $ε=0$ it directly contracts to one point. If $L$ is a Lipschitz constant for $f$ on a sufficiently large segment around $x=0$, then for two functions $u,v$ one gets
$$
\|T[v]-T[u]\|\le εL\|v-u\|\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\int_0^1|G(t,s)|ds=\frac{εL}8\|v-u\|,
$$
so $εL<8$ is sufficient for contractivity.
Now one needs to ensure that if $L$ is the Lipschitz constant on $[-R,R]$ and $\|u\|<R/ε$ then also $\|T[u]\|<R/ε$. Then the Banach fixed-point theorem applies. Continuity of $T$ in $ε$ then implies continuous change of the solutions when $ε$ changes.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that works too. The exercise specifically hinted to use the implicit function theorem (I edited it in now, sorry). Was the previous proof wrong? One more question: is Green function necessary as we are looking for solutions satisfing $v''=g$? I mean: isn't it simpler to proove surjectivity of $v''$ operator using simple integration?

Comment: I don't know about the implicit function theorem, this looks more like the inverse function theorem. You have some non-linear operator $F[u]=g$ and use a partially inverse linear operator $A$ of $F$, so that $A[F[u]]-u$ is small, to construct a fixed-point iteration $T[u]=u-A[F[u]-g]$. This is exactly what I did with the Green kernel.

Comment: I see you mean $F(ε)[u]=u''-f(εu)-εg$, where the implicit function is the dependence of the solution $u_ε$ on $ε$. Then you need that a bounded inverse exists of the linearization $u\mapsto u''$ in $u$ at $ε=0$. Note that you need to observe the boundary conditions also in this case, which again leads to the consideration of the Green operator.

Comment: Yes! As I showed in the proof the map $u\mapsto u''$ is continuous, injective and surjective. Therefore its inverse is bounded as a consequence of the open mapping theorem. As for the boudary condition: can't they be embedded in $C_0^2$?

Comment: It is injective only if you start with $C^2_0$, else the kernel is all linear functions. And yes, then the inverse combined with the embedding into $C^0$ is compact, thus also bounded. If you use such a general argument, you could also use $u\mapsto u''-εf'(0)u$ as linear operator to invert, this would then result in a contraction constant $O(ε^2)$ for the fixed-point iteration.

Comment: Exactly, that's why $T$ takes a $u$ in $C_0^2$. I guess the map $u\mapsto u''-\varepsilon f'(0)u$ works as you suggested with the fixed point iteration method, but $u\mapsto u''$ is the differential of $T$ in $(0,0)$